# Node.js / Appcelerator Titanium / Apache Cordova installations interfering with each other (Mac OS X)

Tags: node.js, cordova, appcelerator

I used to have Titanium studio on my Mac OS X. I wanted to install Apache Cordova alongside it, but somehow my installation of node.js has developed a relationship with Titanium Studio that blocks it. Screenshot at end of this post will give a good idea. Let me also explain.

Using node.js to install Cordova via CLI (Terminal). Titanium has been uninstalled as per the instructions at this URL:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Uninstalling+Studio#UninstallingStudio-MacOSX

As you can see from the Screenshot below, I check node.js isn't installed, install it, check Cordova isn't installed, install it, and the installation show that it is being created in a subfolder of:

```
/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/
```

How is node.js getting hold of this reference, and how can I create a clean install of FRANKLY ANYTHING with node.js on the CLI again?

Please. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I think its because the cordova is not globally accessible, try adding it to your path.